# Count ones in (sliding) window in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, window, rolling-computation

I'm working on anomaly detection project. The result so far is a data frame consisting of a column (of the model) consisting only of "1" and "-1" (for the normal and anomal data points).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'mod1': [1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1]})
```

Now I want to know how many "-1" are within a predefined sliding window of length p. E.g.: looking at the column "mod1" with window length p = 3 it should give me back as output for every row (save in a new column df['n_anomalies_p']): 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3.
How could I get these results?

Maybe using *rolling* or *lambda* function...

I'm new to python. Thank u in advance.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) method is what you are after. Maybe try that and let us know if you have problems.

Comment: The code proposed by @It_is_Chris works fine. I tried an approach using *rolling* and *lambda*, which also gives back the right output BUT: 1) it produces NaNs at the beginning and 2) is way slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See where mod1 is equal to -1 and then do a rolling sum on the boolean values.

```
df['n_anomalies_p'] = df['mod1'].eq(-1).rolling(3,0).sum()

    mod1  n_anomalies_p
0     1            0.0
1     1            0.0
2     1            0.0
3    -1            1.0
4    -1            2.0
5     1            2.0
6    -1            2.0
7    -1            2.0
8    -1            3.0
```